# Changing the url parsing process query name and value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urlparse, url-parsing

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urls = ['https://google.com/path/test.php?q=test','https://twitter.com/path/test.php?q=test&q2=body']
values = ['joker']

for i in urls:
  parsing = urlparse(i)
  queryText =parsing.query 

#output: 
#q=test
#q=test&q2=body
```

I want to change all parameter name and value as below, how can I do?

The result I want:

```
Output:
> https://google.com/path/test.php?joker=test
> https://google.com/path/test.php?q=joker
> https://twitter.com/path/test.php?joker=test&q2=body
> https://twitter.com/path/test.php?q=joker&q2=body
> https://twitter.com/path/test.php?q=test&joker=body
> https://twitter.com/path/test.php?q=test&q2=joker
```

Comment: What are all parameters? You want to replace  of `q` and `test` with values?

Comment: Yeah. I want to list the parameter name and parameter value in Url by changing them in order.

Comment: Would it be ok to store the to be replaced values in a list ? `['q','q2', 'test', 'body']`

Comment: I tried to change the elements in the list and create a url, but I was not successful.